# Fitting bokeh-plot's ordinate in a line to each other

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

Which setting do I have to use to fit the ordinate axis position in the middle to the other two? The bigger y-axis scale moves it away sadly.

I am creating the graphs with:

```
plotting.gridplot(rows)
```

Where

```
rows.append(l)
```

with

```
l = line('x', 'y', source=datasource,
            x_range=x_range[0], ...]
    x_range[0] = l.x_range
```

for multiple `'y'` in the datasource.

The graphs range is coupled via the `x_range`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit hard to do at the moment, unfortunately. We are in the process of integrating cassowary.js for much better layout options of subplots, guides, annotations, etc. In the mean time, you can set the `min_border` (and `min_border_left`, `min_border_top`, etc) on your plots. This will make the border area a minimum size even if it could be smaller. So if you set it large enough to accommodate any labels you expect to see, then it should help make the plot sizes consistent.

Comment: Thank You, this is working as expected. Could You please link me the part of the documentation, or is this part yet to be written? In future it would be very handy to have an (fully working) auto-completion. Most of the time when I press `tab` to get the dropdown auto-completion list, it inserts me (in IPythonNotebook) this text: `.ipynb_checkpoints/`

Comment: This is actually going in the documentation for the upcoming release, and will be up in the ext day or so. It will be in the users guide: http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide.html

We will have to investigate how we might get autocomplete working, we use a fair amount of metaprogramming to reduce boilerplate code across so many glyphs, but it may affect the ability to have auto-complete.